# Sticky element to parent overflow container

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

Note: position of container must be `absolute` caue my pluggin requires that.

```
<div class = "container">
  <div id = "element1">
  </div>
  <div id = "element2">
  </div>
  <div id = "element3">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  background-color: yellow;
}

#element1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#element2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#element3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[image: Should work like this]

Comment: Please list all requirements so that those of us trying to answer the question do not have to keep adjusting answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `#element3` needs to be moved outside the `.container`; but if you need container this way, try ...

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/y3qs8nxv/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div id="element1"></div>
    <div id="element2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="element3"></div>
</div>
```

Try CSS like this ...

```
.container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.inner-container {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#element1 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1em;
}
#element2 {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;
}
#element3 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: -2em;
  bottom: -2em;
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately position of my container must be "absolute", becaue my pluggin required that.

Comment: I've changed the code to accommodate that.  You might want to consider moving this all inside a "wrapper"; that wrapper maybe `.container` with an `.inner-container` and `#element3` as children of there are plugin constraints.

Comment: Changed my answer to accommodate your requests to ave `#element3` inside container.

Comment: yay, my fault, i make mistake in html. That works, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help ... sorry there were so many changes; had to adjust to several requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, `#element3` is inside `.container`.

But in your image, `#element3` is outside `.container`.

You have two options:

1. Write the markup so `#element3` is outside `.container`; or
2. Add javascript which selects `#element3` and then moves it outside `.container`

Comment: indeed. I need to have #element3 inside container, because otherwise my grid becomes broken.

Comment: Right. So, there's your answer then. You can't have `#element3` outside `.container` as you have displayed it in your picture.